# Is it possible to make dynamic tests in testNG?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is it possible to make test sets in testNG which execute based on some condition.

For example, let's say I have captured some 100 odd web-elements and I have 6 common tests to run on each of this element based on the type of element. I have stored all the elements in some list. If the element is of type text box then run test1, test2 and test3. Otherwise, if the element is of type combo box then run test4,5 and 6.

I have seen that there is option of test grouping in testNG, but how can test grouping can be used in above context?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted a link as to what resource you have looked at to understand "test-grouping".

Comment: Hi @Seanny123 i tried searching in the testNG docs as well as in testNG tutorials. but couldn't find anything suitable to my requirement. hence i am asking here. if anyone has encountered my scenario or guide  me to some pointers?

Comment: @Mrunal Gosar: You're probably looking for *data providers* - see the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Comment: @reinierpost i had gone through the documentation of data providers but i didn't find content suitable to my query. if you could just explain things with some small example,then it will be of great help. any small example will do. TIA

Comment: @Mrunal Gosar: well, you can write a data provider that provides all the textbox elements and another that provides all the other elements.

Comment: @reinierpost Some background : i have a method which fetches all the control at run time on a page, then on the basis of type of the control tests should run for that page. similarly i have a driver script which navigates to different pages and then i want the control tests to run. thats why i need the feature of making dynamic tests in testng. anything for this?

Comment: My idea was this: call the method that collects all the controls, store the collection in a variable in your test class, write two methods that list  the textbox controls and the other controls, respectively, wrapped inside singleton tuples, and use those as data providers on your test methods. I don't know why that wouldn't work for you.